# UMD on sites using RequireJS not working?

Tags: javascript, requirejs, umd

When I go to the vast majority of websites, open up the console and paste the following code:

```
(function(global, appName, app) {
    if (typeof define === "function" && typeof define.amd === "object") {
        console.log("AMD/RequireJS");
        define(app);
        console.log("defined app");
    } else if (typeof module !== "undefined") {
        console.log("CommonJS");
        module.exports = app(global);
        console.log("defined with module.exports");
    } else {
        console.log("Browser");
        global[appName] = app(global);
        console.log("defined as global");
    }
})(this, "App", function(global) {
    "use strict";
    console.log("defining getThis");
    function getThis() {
        console.log('i got it!');
    }
    return {
        getThis: getThis
    };
});
console.log("finished IIFE");
App.getThis();
```

I get the following output:

```
Browser
defining getThis
defined as global
finished IIFE
i got it!
```

If I paste that same code into the console of a site that uses RequireJS such as www.bestbuy.com or www.homedepot.com it fails with this output:

```
AMD/RequireJS
defined app
finished IIFE
Uncaught ReferenceError: App is not defined at <anonymous>:27:1
```

I've tried changing the line `define(app);` to `define(['App'], app);` with no effect.

I have been googling and puttering around with this for hours now and am at my wit's end.  I thought the UMD pattern was UNIVERSAL hence its name.  What gives?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it all depends on how are you going to use your script. If you know you are going to use your script in a browser without `RequireJS`, then it is OK the way you are testing it.

```
App.getThis();
```

Because it is in the global object, in the case of a browser, `window`.

But if you know `RequireJS` is present, then you need to `require` your app.

```
require(["App"], function(App){
    App.getThis();
});
```

And if `NodeJS`

```
const App = require('App');
```

But I've not tested this one.

Also, I recommend you to change `define(app);` by `define(appName, app);`

Hope it helps